# gridView - array in strings.xml

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm trying to create a multilingual app, but my home page is a gridView made of images and textViews. When I created a list in Java (like this):

```
String textoList[] = {"Visto", "Alojamento", "C.P.F.", "Alimentação", "Carteirinha", "Guia", "Registro", "Informações", "Assistência", "Biblioteca", "Calendário", "Transporte", "INT", "Intérprete", "F.A.Q."};
```

it worked very well. But I realized that I shouldn't create a list in Java, but use an array that is already create in the strings.xml file so that way my app can be translated. Basically, I want the texts from this array. How can I do this?

Can someone give me a hand, please? If someone would like to test it, the complete code is:

```
    package br.com.unbparaestrangeiros.unbparaestrangeiros;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    GridView gridView;

    Resources r = getResources();
    String[] textoList = r.getStringArray(R.array.itens);

    //String textoList[] = {"Visto", "Alojamento", "C.P.F.", "Alimentação", "Carteirinha", "Guia", "Registro", "Informações", "Assistência", "Biblioteca", "Calendário", "Transporte", "INT", "Intérprete", "F.A.Q."};

    int textoImagem[] = {R.drawable.visto, R.drawable.alojamento, R.drawable.cpf, R.drawable.alimentacao, R.drawable.carteirinha, R.drawable.guia,  R.drawable.registro, R.drawable.informacoes, R.drawable.assistencia,  R.drawable.biblioteca, R.drawable.calendario, R.drawable.transporte,  R.drawable.informacoes, R.drawable.interprete, R.drawable.perguntas};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inicio);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

        GridAdapter adapter = new GridAdapter(MainActivity.this, textoImagem, textoList);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        Intent case0 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Visto.class);
                        startActivity(case0);
                        break;

                    case 1:
                        Intent case1 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alojamento.class);
                        startActivity(case1);
                        break;

                    case 2:
                        Intent case2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CPF.class);
                        startActivity(case2);
                        break;

                    case 3:
                        Intent case3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Alimentacao.class);
                        startActivity(case3);
                        break;

                    case 4:
                        Intent case4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Carteirinha.class);
                        startActivity(case4);
                        break;

                    case 5:
                        Intent case5 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Guia.class);
                        startActivity(case5);
                        break;

                    case 6:
                        Intent case6 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Registro.class);
                        startActivity(case6);
                        break;

                    case 7:
                        Intent case7 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Informacoes.class);
                        startActivity(case7);
                        break;

                    case 8:
                        Intent case8 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Assistencia.class);
                        startActivity(case8);
                        break;

                    case 9:
                        Intent case9 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Biblioteca.class);
                        startActivity(case9);
                        break;

                    case 10:
                        Intent case10 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Calendario.class);
                        startActivity(case10);
                        break;

                    case 11:
                        Intent case11 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Transporte.class);
                        startActivity(case11);
                        break;

                    case 12:
                        Intent case12 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Assessoria.class);
                        startActivity(case12);
                        break;

                    case 13:
                        Intent case13 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Interprete.class);
                        startActivity(case13);
                        break;

                    case 14:
                        Intent case14 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Perguntas.class);
                        startActivity(case14);
                        break;

                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: `String[] textoList[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itens);` from strings.xml in oncreate. Note you have  `String[] textoList = r.getStringArray(R.array.itens);` . `getResources(`) needs a context. Context is available once activity is created. Move your code inside onCreate

Comment: what is the error

Comment: "But I realized that I shouldn't create a list in Java, but use an array that is already create in the strings.xml file" - `String[] textoList` is not a `List`, you are already using an array of strings obtained directly from the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file if not already present called `array.xml` in `app/src/main/res/values`. You can add your strings like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string-array name="itens">
        <item>Visto</item>
        <item>Alojamento</item>
        <!--Add your other words here-->
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And you can access them using `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itens);` from your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
String[] textoList;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inicio);

    textoList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.itens);
}
```

And your `itens` array in `strings.xml` as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    ...............
    ......................
    <string-array name="itens">
        <item>Visto</item>
        <item>Alojamento</item>
        <item>C.P.F.</item>
        <item>Alimentação</item>
        <item>Carteirinha</item>
        <item>Guia</item>
        <item>Registro</item>
        ................
        .......................
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: If my answer seems useful then you can mark it as right answer and vote it up. Thanks in advance :)